# ipv6 value assigned to a variable in bash script behaves wrong

Tags: bash, shell, echo, posix

I have run a situation where i assign a variable with ipv6 address and then try to do an operation by concatenating ipv6 with square brackets []. In one of the scenarios bash executes what ever is present inside the [] and replaces the entire value with 1.

Some thing like

```
#!/bin/sh
llipv6=xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:3a17%bond0
echo "/bin/bash -c "$REST_CLI serverlogs --url [$llipv6]""
```

When i run the script the output is

*/bin/bash -c "abc.sh serverlogs --url 1*

Another amazing thing which is happening here is that if i change the ipv6 addresses last two digit above 19 , it prints correctly

```
llipv6=xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:3a21%bond0
echo "/bin/bash -c "$REST_CLI serverlogs --url [$llipv6]""
```

The output is 
*/bin/bash -c "abc.sh serverlogs --url [xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:3a21%bond0]*

I am not understanding the issue here.

I just modified the way i am concatenating the ipv6 like below and it seems to work fine.

```
#!/bin/sh
llipv6=xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:3a17%bond0
echo "/bin/bash -c "$REST_CLI serverlogs --url "[$llipv6]"""
```

Please suggest the right way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most examples have a typo: you set `llipv6`, but try to echo `llipv5`.

Answer (score 0):

### Why it doesn't work

You are misusing shell quoting.

You cannot nest double quotes like you are (`"something1 "something2""`).

When `sh` sees

```
echo "/bin/bash -c "$REST_CLI serverlogs --url [$llipv6]""
```

It sees the strings `/bin/bash -c $REST_CLI`, `serverlogs`, `--url`, `[$llipv6]` (with an appended empty string `""`, which does nothing).

Now, because you're misusing shell quotes, I'm going to assume that you assigned `REST_CLI` in a way that causes it to have the value `"abc.sh` (with a leading double quote).

So the shell interprets `/bin/bash -c $REST_CLI` as `/bin/bash -c "abc.sh`. The interpretation of `serverlogs` and `--url` is fine. But then we get to `[$llipv6]`.

In a POSIX shell, the syntax `[some-letters]` is a glob pattern. Just like `*` refers to "everything that completes to a file name", `[abc]` refers to "everything that completes a file name with a, b, or c".

example:

```
$ ls
aaa  bbb  ccc
$ echo [ab]*
aaa bbb
```

So when the shell sees `[$llipv6]`, it turns into `[llipv6=xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:3a17%bond0]`, which is a glob pattern that matches every file if its name is one of `:`, `%`, `0`, `1`, `3`, `7`, `a`, `b`, `d`, `n`, `o`, `x`.

So in the directory where you're running this script, you have a file called `1`, which is why instead of the IPv6 address you're getting `1` at the end, and also why when you're going above 19, `1` is no longer a glob character.

Then another arcane behavior of the posix shell kicks in. If the glob pattern matches no file, then instead of returning 0 files, it returns the pattern, in the "above 19" case - `[xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:3a21%bond0]` - which is why it works fine.

Also note that with your modified way:

```
echo "/bin/bash -c "$REST_CLI serverlogs --url "[$llipv6]"""
```

she shell sees the first 3 strings the same, only now it sees `"[$llipv6]"` quoted, and when it's quoted, globbing is not applied, which is why this version also works fine.

### How to make it work

Regarding the nested shell quoting, inside `""` you can use `''` for quoting (and vice versa):

```
#!/bin/sh
llipv6=xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:3a17%bond0
echo "/bin/bash -c '$REST_CLI serverlogs --url [$llipv6]'"
```

Inside the double-quoted string, `'` has no special meaning. Output:

```
/bin/bash -c 'abc.sh serverlogs --url [xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:3a17%bond0]'
```

And if you run the output as a command, then the single quotes (`'`) will kick in and work properly.